# Magento discover if phtml is part of main product page or related product tab

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I'm customizing my Magento webstore to use rich snippets, so that I had changed the price.phtml to add the itemprop="price" to the price span. The problemn is that I'm getting various itemprop attributes when I have related or agregate products.

I would like to know if there is a way to get the block parent name in php, so I'll be able to ignore the itemprop rendering out of the main product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `price.phtml` template and the corresponding block is almost always called via `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract::getPriceHtml($product, $displayMinimalPrice, $idSuffix)`, and therefore has no parent.

To detect from which blocks it is used, you could update those blocks to add something like `$product->setIsCalledFromParentBlock(true)` before the `getPriceHtml()` call, and then test the value of `$product->getIsCalledFromParentBlock()` in `price.phtml`

Comment: Dear bImage, I tried your code on price.phtml and I'm getting a internal server error, do you have an ideia of what Im doing wrong ?

Comment: When called from `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract::getPriceHtml()`, price block has no parent, so `$this->getParentBlock()` returns null

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to get a developer-toolbar extension like mgt-commerce is offering one for free! You get all kind of information straight in your webbrowser.

Good luck!